# Enumeration of a Linq.EntitySet

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm super new to .net and C#, this seems like a basic problem to me, but no amount of searching or debugging has resolved the issue yet.

I have this code in a repository class:

```
// Attempt #1
var results = from d in db.Documents
              join f in db.DocumentFrames on d.Id equals f.DocumentId
              select d;
return results.ToList();

// Attempt #2
var options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Document>(d => d.DocumentFrames);
db.LoadOptions = options;

var results = db.Documents.ToList();
```

The code returns what I expect (a `List<Document>`). My controller then does this:

```
List<APIDocument> transformed = new List<APIDocument>();

foreach(Document document in documents)
{
    transformed.Add(this.PrepareModelForResponse(document));
}

return transformed;
```

The code for `PrepareModelForResponse`:

```
private APIDocument PrepareModelForResponse(Document document)
{
    APIDocument response = new APIDocument();
    response.setPropertiesFromObject(document);
    return response;
}
```

I'm preparing each Document for output (this code is part of an API), and error happens when I do this:

```
public void setPropertiesFromObject(Document document)
{
    this.Id = document.Id;
    this.OriginalFileUrl = document.OriginalFileUrl;
    this.CreatedAt = document.CreatedAt;

    foreach (DocumentFrame frame in document.DocumentFrames)
    {
        APIDocumentFrame newFrame = new APIDocumentFrame();
        newFrame.setPropertiesFromObject(frame);
        this.DocumentFrames.Add(newFrame);
    }
}
```

I get an `InvalidCastException` "Specified cast is not valid" on the foreach statement, here is the stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Byte()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetByte(Int32 i)
   at Read_DocumentFrame(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.Load()
   at System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at InDesignAPI.Models.API.APIDocument.setPropertiesFromObject(Document document) in c:\FakeProjectPath\Models\API\APIDocument.cs:line 23
   at InDesignAPI.Controllers.DocumentsController.PrepareModelForResponse(Document document) in c:\FakeProjectPath\Controllers\DocumentsController.cs:line 144
   at InDesignAPI.Controllers.DocumentsController.GetDocument(Int32 id) in c:\FakeProjectPath\Controllers\DocumentsController.cs:line 42
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Could I vary my query in a way that the documents in the list automatically contain the DocumentFrames?

While debugging this problem, document.DocumentFrames displays the DocumentFrames objects if I click on results view in the debug pane, which indicates the data has loaded correctly, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Can you post the code that is not working? Also, in C#, you write `List<Document>` for generics.

Comment: So it seems like you can iterate through your List<Document> but then for a document you cannot run any methods on the documents property DocumentFrames.

If you change the code in your repository class to "return db.Documents.Include(d => d.DocumentFrames).ToList();" What will you then get?

Comment: @manuFS - updated with code and the correction you submitted.

Comment: @Sasse - I get an error when I try using .Include:

Error 1 'System.Data.Linq.Table<Document>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table<Document>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Now when you've updated your code it seems to me that I would need to se some more code. :p What does "this" refer to in the foreach-loop?

What if you tried only this on your Repository "return db.Documents.ToList();" Will this leed to that DocumentFrames are "null" up in GUI?

Comment: Is it on the first time it throws exception? If you remove the code in the foreach, will it still throw the exception?

Comment: @sasse - added a lot more code, no error if I remove the foreach, but I also don't get to populate the DocumentFrames attribute.

I'm transforming the output from the database using stub objects that copy the fields I want to expose in the API.

Comment: Can you show the content of "setPropertiesFromObject" method for the APIDocumentFrame class?

Comment: When you're writing "this.DocumentFrames.Add" is "this.DocumentFrames" defined as a List or is it still "null" ? If still null then before the foreach-statement you should add "this.DocumentFrames = new List<APIDocumentFrames>();"

Comment: @Sasse - the code halts at the foreach loop, not sure what the merit of showing any additional code is, it's not getting that far at the moment.

I added the initialisation of this.DocumentFrames but again, it's not referenced until we're inside the foreach loop, which hasn't happened yet :(

Comment: @Farid - Okay, so even if you remove all the code inside the foreach the error occured? I mean, keep the foreach-loop but remove the code inside.

Comment: Can you include the whole error message please. =)

Comment: @Sasse - Added stack trace and error message.

Comment: I've reduced code down to this (replacing the foreach), gives the same error.

`var enumerator = document.DocumentFrames.GetEnumerator();`

Comment: What's happening if you write document.DocumentFrames.ToList() in setPropertiesForObject(Document document) method? Not in the foreach statemaent but before. What happends if you write "var firstFrame = document.DocumentFrames.FirstOrDefault();" in the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a good deal of messing around, I recreated my partial classes by deleting everything from my dbml file, and dragging all the tables back on.

There was an inconsistency between my generated class files and the database, so parsing DocumentFrame objects was returning an error no matter what context it happened in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an explicit join and a query here, because EntityFramework knows how to join with DocumentFrames already.

```
var options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Document>(d => d.DocumentFrames);
db.LoadOptions = options;

var results = db.Documents.ToList();
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Data.Linq.Table<Document>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table<Document>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Updated code runs, but still getting same error with the foreach. Thanks for trying to help twice :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework you can access document.DocumentFrames using Relationships and Navigation Properties. Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj713564.aspx)